# MediaDevices.getUserMedia() support for ios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc, mobile-safari, getusermedia

I was trying to get browser settings details (Camera, Microphone permission) in ReactJS project. Based on that I will show some error message in the UI if it is blocked. I use the following code.

```
useEffect(()=>{
collectUserLogData();
},[]);

const collectUserLogData = () => {
    navigator.getMedia =
      navigator.getUserMedia ||
      navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
      navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
      navigator.msGetUserMedia;

    navigator.getMedia(
      { video: true },
      () => {
        setCamera(true);
        console.log("Permission_", "camera ON");
      },
      () => {
        console.log("Permission_", "Camera OFF");
      }
    );

    navigator.getMedia(
      { audio: true },
      () => {
        setMic(true);
        console.log("Permission_", "Mic ON");
      },
      () => {
        console.log("Permission_", "Mic OFF");
      }
    );

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      () => {
        setLocation(true);
        console.log("Permission_", "Geo ON");
      },
      () => {
        console.log("Permission_", "Geo OFF");
      }
    );
  };
```

This is working in the windows and android browsers but not in the ios browsers. I did not test it in the mac ios. The popup is not showing in ios browsers. How to fix this.

Comment: hat does setCamera(true); do? Did you try to set the srcObj of a video element to the stream you get to verify camera is working or not?

Comment: Facing the same issue.. Were u able to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

getUserMedia() works properly on recent version of iOS. Generally 11.1 and beyond are OK.

To troubleshoot this stuff, you need to connect your iOS device to a Mac and use the Safari remote debugging setup. That way you can get a console and javascript debugger.

enumerateDevices() works if you have already used getUserMedia() to ask the user for permission to use the camera and/or mic. Without that permission, the emumerateDevices() results are vague or missing. This is to prevent browser fingerprinting. Because cybercreeps.

In the versions of iOS where getUserMedia actually works, you don't need to look around in various namespaces to find it. `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` is sufficient.

Here's code like what I've used to enumerate media sources on all kinds of different browser platforms incl. iOS, Android, and various desktops.  I've used `async / await` because it's an easy way to handle the Promise returned by getUserMedia().  But you could use the Promise directly if you wish. (Please note I've edited this  code to remove my application-specific stuff, but I haven't debugged it.)

```
async function enumerateSources() {
    if(      navigator 
          && navigator.mediaDevices 
          && typeof navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices === 'function' ) {
      try {
        /* open a generic stream to get permission to see devices; 
         * Mobile Safari insists */
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
                { video: true, audio: true} )
        let devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
        const cameras = devices.filter( device => {
          return device.kind === 'videoinput'
        })
        if (cameras.length >= 1) console.log ('cameras avail')
        const mics = devices.filter( device => {
          return device.kind === 'audioinput'
        })
        if (mics.length >= 1) console.log ('mics avail')

       /* release stream */
        const tracks = stream.getTracks()
        if( tracks ) {
          for( let t = 0; t < tracks.length; t++ ) tracks[t].stop()
        }
        return ({cameras, mics})
      } catch(error) {
        /* user refused permission, or media busy, or some other problem */
        console.error(error.name, error.message)
        return {cameras:[], mics:[]})
      }
    }
    else throw ('media device stuff not available in this browser')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The new API works like

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()
```

I suggest you to add to the support logic statement of yours to supersede all the others which are the old API.

You then need to to use the stream that promise resolve with. You can have a `video` element in our DOM and set its `srcObj` property with the stream.

```
navigator.getMedia(
      { video: true },
      (stream) => {
        video.srcObj = stream;
        setCamera(true);
        console.log("Permission_", "camera ON");
      },
      () => {
        console.log("Permission_", "Camera OFF");
      }
    );
```

Comment: If I use this new syntax then the popup works fine in desktop browsers and even after giving permissions the camera is not working

Comment: Is there any possibility to get browser details (Camera, Microphone) without overriding the default popup. Because before using these navigator class it was working fine. Now it's overriding the default popup and that cause this issue in ios browsers.

Comment: What do you mean by "browser details"? Devices? `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` and [`navigator.mediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getSupportedConstraints)

Comment: I need to know whether camera or microphone is blocked or not